# Angular $resource returns too many results

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I don't know if my question makes any sense as I'm a bit confused to what is happening here myself, but I have a service that returns information about offices. There seems to be nothing wrong with this and it returns data like this:

```
[
    {
        "mainContact": {
                "phoneNumbers":[
                    {"key":1,"number":"22555555","type":"Mobile"}
                ],
                "key":1,
                "name":"Ola Dunk",
                "email":"oladunk@lol.no"
            },
        "secretary": {
            "phoneNumbers": [
                {
                "key":2,
                "number":"22666666",
                "type":"Home"
                }
            ],
            "key":2,
            "name":"Kari Norrmann",
            "email":"kari@test.no"
        },
        "key":1,
        "specialRequirements":null,
        "name":"Ola Dunk",
        "address":"Test",
        "doctorCount":10,
        "presumedPurchaseAmount":100000,
        "phoneNumber":"22222222",
        "membershipStatus":1
    }
]
```

I tried using $resource to get the data using

```
var r = $resource('http://localhost:60297/api/office');
console.log(r.query());
```

I use query() over get() since this is the default get all service when no id is specified or some other selector. It just happens to return only the one test office I've created because that's the only office that exists presently.

My problem is what you can see in my console which I've screenshotted here:

[image]

That's just the tip of the iceberg. The result keeps getting repeated. Just to check I tried using $http instead of $resource and then it works just fine.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because object 'self-assigned', you can try in console:

```
var test = { foo : 'bar'}; 
test.foo = test;
```

and get same thing. The question is: why it bothers you?

Comment: This may sound incredibly stupid, but isn't that a bad thing? Is there a way to make it so it doesn't happen or does it just not matter that this happens?

Comment: it was bad thing back in ie7 times, but now it's ok. I think it's natural behavior for angular $resource and promises.